# I want to create a simple singleton cluster and send message from a remote node

Tags: akka, akka-http, akka-cluster

Here i have created a singleton actor. The master and the seed node is the same. From a different project i am trying to add into the cluster and want to send message. I am able to join in the cluster but cannot be able to send message.

My master and seed node:

```
     package Demo
     import akka.actor._
     import akka.cluster.singleton.{ClusterSingletonManager, ClusterSingletonManagerSettings, ClusterSingletonProxy, ClusterSingletonProxySettings}
     import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
     import scala.concurrent.duration._
     object MainObject1 extends App{
     DemoMain1.start(8888)

     }
     object DemoMain1 {
       val role = "test"
       val singletonname = "Ruuner"
       val mastername = "Master"
       def start(port: Int): ActorSystem = {
         val conf = ConfigFactory.parseString(
           s"""
     |akka.actor.provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
     |
     |akka.remote.netty.tcp.port = $port
     |akka.remote.netty.tcp.hostname = 127.0.0.1
     |akka.cluster.roles = ["$role"]
     |akka.cluster.seed-nodes = ["akka.tcp://DemoMain1@127.0.0.1:8888"]

   """.stripMargin
)
val system = ActorSystem("DemoMain1", conf)
val settings = ClusterSingletonManagerSettings(system).withRole(role)
val manager = ClusterSingletonManager.props(Props[DemoMain1], PoisonPill, settings)
val actor=system.actorOf(manager, mastername)
system
       }

       class DemoMain1 extends Actor with Identification {
         import context._
         override def preStart(): Unit = {
           println(s"Master is created with id $id in $system")
           println(self.path.address.host)
          system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(100.seconds, self, 'exit)

         }

         override def receive : Receive={
  case 'exit => println("$id is exiting")
    context stop self
    //SupervisorStrategy.Restart


  case msg => println(s"messasge from $system is $msg  ")

      sender() ! 'how
         }
       }
     }
```

The other node which is trying to join the cluster and send message.

```
     import akka.actor._
     import akka.cluster.singleton.{ClusterSingletonProxy, ClusterSingletonProxySettings}
     import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
     import scala.concurrent.duration._
     object Ping extends App{
       def ping: ActorSystem = {
         val conf = ConfigFactory.parseString(
           s"""
              |akka.actor.provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
     |
     |akka.remote.netty.tcp.port = 0
     |akka.remote.netty.tcp.hostname = 127.0.0.1
     |akka.cluster.roles = ["slave"]
     |akka.cluster.seed-nodes = ["akka.tcp://DemoMain1@127.0.0.1:8888"]
     |akka.cluster.auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
   """.stripMargin
)
val system = ActorSystem("DemoMain1", conf)
system.actorOf(Props[Ping])
system
       }
       class Ping extends Actor {
         import context._
         val path = "akka.tcp://DemoMain1@127.0.0.1:8888/DemoMain1/user/Master/actor"
        val settings = ClusterSingletonProxySettings(system).withRole("slave")
         val actor = context.actorOf(ClusterSingletonProxy.props(path, settings))
         val pingInterval = 1.seconds
         override def preStart(): Unit = {
           system.scheduler.schedule(pingInterval, pingInterval) {
             println(s"Locate Ping $system")
             actor ! 'hi
           }
         }

         override def receive: Receive = {
           case msg => println(s"The message is $msg")

         }
       }
       Ping.ping
     }
```

If i give ip addresses of the system then also the message s not sent.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the `role` in your `ClusterSingletonProxySettings(system).withRole("slave")` settings for your `Ping` actor doesn't match that of your `ClusterSingletonManagerSettings(system).withRole(role)` where `role = "test"`.

`ClusterSingletonProxy` is supposed to be present on all nodes with the specified `role` on which the cluster is set up, hence its `role` settings should match `ClusterSingletonManager`'s. Here's a [sample configuration](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/cluster-usage.html#router-example-with-pool-of-remote-deployed-routees).

Comment: i tried keeping the same name also but it is not working